# SASS setup - have to close and reopen webpage for changes to take effect

Tags: css, sass

I have sass setup, and it currently updates any scss to CSS via  the command sass --watch scss:css.

however, whenever an update is made to the .scss file - it will not show if I simply refresh the webpage in safari, I must close the page down and re-open the weblink again.

This is becoming increasingly tedious, my SASS setup seems to be fine - not sure if this is a common issue that can be fixed.

Please keep in mind that as soon as I save any changes in .scss it's automatically updated in css.

Many thanks

Comment: Seems most likely browser caching, try a "hard refresh" CMD SHIFT R (on Safari 9+)

Comment: It might be possible on dev environt (not good on production) to set your LINK href attribute to have a dynamic querystring : style.css?nocache=<?php echo(time()); ?> same file, but different url

Comment: @Matt.C hi matt, I just tried clearing my cache. If I clear the cache then refresh the page it works. However, only the one time. i.e. 1 ) change made to .scss 2) clear cache 3 ) refresh page, wallah it works. but then if I make any further changes I again have to clear the cache in order to refresh.

Comment: What is your delopment environment? local files, or an actual server?

Comment: it's just local files :)

Comment: Probably best to just diable caching in safari https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/TheDevelopMenu/TheDevelopMenu.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH7-SW1

Comment: thanks, this work - I've accepted your answer though, if you want to modify it with the disable cache solution too =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems mostly likely this is the browser caching the css file

Try using a hard refresh, if you are on Safari 9+ this should be doable by pressing

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Alternativly if you're working in a devlopment environment you could add a dynamic query string to the css link, creating a unique url each time, but referencing the same file forcing the browser to redownload the file each time the page is refreshed

```
<link href="/path/to/style.css?nocache=<?php echo(microtime(true)); ?>"  />
```

If you are fully in control of the server you are working on you might also look at making sure the server isn't set up to add caching headers, etags or other rules for static files

The other option, and likely also the easiest is to disable caching in safari from the [Develop menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/TheDevelopMenu/TheDevelopMenu.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH7-SW1) (you may need to enable the devlop menu under advanced in preferences)